# Slf4j vs Log4j - which one to use for logging in Spark cluster mode?

Tags: logging, apache-spark, log4j, slf4j

What is the difference between Slf4j and Log4j logging in Spark? How can Log4j be used for logging in Spark cluster mode?

Answer (score 3):

Spark uses Log4j for logging, so you also can use it.

Note that Slf4j is only facade and you can use Slf4j with log4j, i.e. to have possibility to use slf4j's syntax in messages, like `log.info("Message: {}", message);`

[Here](https://www.mapr.com/blog/how-log-apache-spark) you've got tutorial about logging in Spark